# @BeforeClass and @AfterClass methodis not executed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
package baseClasses;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

public final class InitSetUp {


    private WebDriver driver;
    private static String baseDriverPath="D:\\driver\\";
    
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    private void setDriver(String browserName, String url) {
        switch(browserName) {
        case "Chrome" : {
            System.out.println("Setting chorme driver please wait");
            driver = initChromeDriver(url);
        }

        case "Firefox" :{
            System.out.println("Setting firefox driver please wait");
            driver = initFirfoxDriver(url);
        }
        case "IE" : {
            
        }

        }
    }
    
    private WebDriver initChromeDriver(String url) {
        System.out.println("initializing chorme driver please wait");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", baseDriverPath + "chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("Navigating to given url please wait");
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        return driver;
    }
    private WebDriver initFirfoxDriver(String url) {
        System.out.println("initializing Firefox driver please wait");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", baseDriverPath + "geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("Navigating to given url please wait");
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        return driver;
    }
    
    @Parameters({"browserName","openURL"})
    @BeforeClass
    public void initBorwser(String browserName,String openURL) {
        System.out.println("Initializing Class..");
        try {
            setDriver(browserName, openURL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error....." + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("Quiting please wait");
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

And here is another Class

```
package testClasses;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import baseClasses.InitSetUp;

public class OpenTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    
    public OpenTest() {
        System.out.println("In Open Test");
        InitSetUp baseclass= new InitSetUp();
        driver = baseclass.getDriver();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void openBroser() {
        System.out.println("TEST ONE");
    }
    
}
```

And TESTNG XML--------

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TESTX" verbose="1" >
 <parameter name="browserName" value="Firefox" />
    <parameter name="openURL" value="google.com" />
  <test name="TestOpen" >
    <classes>
       <class name="testClasses.OpenTest" />
        <class name="baseClasses.InitSetUp" />
    </classes>
  </test>
 

</suite>
```

When I run the above XML in testNG it is not executing the methods @BeforeCLass and @AfterClass. Its shows the output as--

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.2.0
In Open Test
TEST ONE

## ===============================================
TESTX
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Answer (score 1):

Your code is faulty...
To answer your question why these: @beforeclass @afterclass aren't called, it is because you didn't extend the InitSetUp class to the OpenTest

so instead of
`public final class InitSetUp`  change it to `public class InitSetUp`

And apply the inheritance here

instead of `public class OpenTest` change it to `public class OpenTest extends InitSetUp`

Comment: if I create an object of InitSetUp even then @BeforeClass will not call??

Comment: Nope, You have to have a "Testbase" class where you initiate the Webdriver, that the other tests will use. Also currently you have 3 of them the in InitSetup private WebDriver driver; +  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); in the chrome method + another Webdriver in OpenTest class.